# Is there a way to add more than one variable in flask (Variable Rules)

Tags: python, flask

Is there a way to build dynamic URLs in Python Flask using multiple variables

The normal case is :

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/hello/<name>')
def hello_name(name):
   return 'Hello %s!' % name

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

What I am trying to ask is :

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/hello/<name><your_pp><etc>')
def hello_name(name):
   return 'Hello %s!' % name 

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

Is it possible if we use converters like int:your_pp, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to specify the different parameters in the method definition

```
@app.route('/hello/<name><int:your_pp><float:etc>')
def hello_name(name, your_pp, etc):
    return 'Hello %s %d %f!' % (name, your_pp, etc)
```

But wouls leads to problem as you the code could split differently of your hopes, better use separators, `/` is the more common

```
@app.route('/hello/<name>/<int:your_pp>/<float:etc>')
def hello_name(name, your_pp, etc):
    return 'Hello %s %d %f!' % (name, your_pp, etc)
```

Use like `mydomain.com/hello/johnname/123/456.789`

Comment: How could it possibly tell where the `int` ends and the `float` begins?  To give a concrete example, is `111.1` supposed to be `(1, 11.1)` or `(11, 1.1)`?  There would have to be some separator between the fields.

Comment: I am actually new to this so can you please show me an example URL in the above case

Comment: @vIvId_gOat you try rules and don’t know what it does ? Look my edit at the end

Comment: Thanks @azro now I can proceed to create my API

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're trying to do a query like this :
`host:port/hello?name=john&last_name=doe ...`

If is that the case request from flask can wrap up this into a dictionary like this:

```
from flask import request
@app.route('/hello')
def query():
    args = request.args
    print(args)
    return "example string", 200
```

The printed value will be something like this:
`ImmutableMultiDict([('name', 'john'), ('last_name', 'doe'))])`

This post will help you more
https://pythonise.com/series/learning-flask/flask-query-strings